# Asp.net core 1.0 rc2 with angular 2 importing external libraries

Tags: angular, asp.net-core-1.0

I have a problem importing _underscore library to my Angular 2, what i did is:

1. Added `"underscore": "^1.8.3"` to my package.json file under
   `"dependencies"` section (which in my understanding pulled underscore to my node_modules directory
2. I updated my `gulpfile.js` and told it to pull `underscore-min.js` from node_modules to `"./wwwroot/libs"`
3. After that i went to my `systemjs.config.js` file and added  `'underscore': 'libs/underscore'` to "map" section, i also added `'underscore': {defaultExtension:'js'}` under packages section of same file - this should in my understanding point to underscore-min.js once i ask for it in my angular2 component.
4. I added `<script src="libs/underscore/underscore-min.js"></script>` to my index.html file
5. At the end i went to my Component and added `import * as _ from 'underscore';` which returns error saying it "Cannot find module 'underscore'." - which i pointed to in step 3

If it metters, i used https://medium.com/@s_eschweiler/using-external-libraries-with-angular-2-87e06db8e5d1#.4bzkvnw1n as a reference...

Any idea what am I doing wrong here? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to install type definitions for TypeScript compiler to know about `underscore`. It's likely that the guide was written for a JavaScript project in mind, not TypeScript.

At the moment, the best way to get type definitions is to use the [Typings](https://github.com/typings/typings) tool.

1. Install typings globally. You only need to do this once per machine

   `npm install typings --global`
2. Install the `underscore` type definitions in your project

   `typings install dt~underscore --global`

You may also need to reference the type definitions in your code, depending on your project setup. The [Typings FAQ](https://github.com/typings/typings/blob/master/docs/faq.md#module-resolutions) has examples on how to do this.

Comment: Ok, what i forgot to mention is that i already installed typings, but i didn't install type definition for `underscore`, after installing it, i got new folder inside typings/globals which is called underscore and it has index.d.ts inside, however i still receive same error... Thanks for such a quick answer by the way...

Comment: You may need to reference these type definitions. Either - have a tsconfig.json in your project root, or include a `///` reference in your code. If you don't already have a tsconfig.json, it may be easier to have a `///` reference. E.g. `/// <reference path="../typings/index.d.ts" />` Make sure the path is correct. Typings will generate an index.d.ts with references to all installed type definitions - you just need to reference this file.

Comment: Hehehe, silly me... Thanks a lot bro, it works now! I'm very new to TS and I obviously need some more reading to do about how all of this staff works : ) Thanks once again for your time.

Comment: Glad to help. I've run into the same issue before - glad to save someone the trouble. I'll edit the reply to include the reference part.